# OptaPlanner: Difference between filtering during or after join

Tags: constraints, filtering, optaplanner

Is there any difference, semantically or performance wise, between

```
cf.forEach(Entity.class)
        .join(cf.forEach(Entity.class),
                Joiners.filtering(myBiPredicate)))
        ...
```

vs

```
cf.forEach(Entity.class)
        .join(cf.forEach(Entity.class))
        .filter(myBiPredicate)))
        ...
```

Also, are the `Joiners` executed in the order given? (I.e. is it advised to, for example, put filters that prune a lot of pairs early in the argument list?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question - no, there is no practical difference between the two constraints. `Joiners.filtering(...)` exists so that you can apply a filter in `ifExists(...)` calls; when doing a normal join, you might as well just do a filter after the join.

To answer your second question, I [wrote an entire blog post](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/05/25/WritingFastConstraintStreamsSecretRecipe.html). Yes, it is better to prune early.

Comment: Great blog post. Thanks Lukáš! (Just to clarify, putting a `Joiners.filtering` early in the argument list, causes it to be executed earlier in the stream?)

Comment: The filtering joiner is a bit special - it may or may not be put at the end of the argument list, depending on the CS implementation being used. For any other joiner, the position in the list is respected.

Comment: Good info. Thanks again Lukáš!